# google charts api - pie chart is not displaying

Tags: php, google-visualization

I am trying to create a piechart dynamically by using Google Chart api. i am taking values from the database. I am not getting how exactly this can be done.

```
$resultViewed = $this->model_report_product->getMostViewed();
        $stringResult ="var data= google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([ ['Product', 'Views'],";

     foreach($resultViewed as $results)
     {               
                 $stringResult = $stringResult . "['".$results['name']."',".$results['quantity']."],";
                 break;     
     }
     $stringResult .= "]);";

    $this->data['Viewed'] = $stringResult;
```

When i run this, it gives Chart heading but pie chart is not displayed but it says No Data.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a variable in memory between php to html.  You have to print it out to pass it to html.  So where you have:

```
return $stringResult;
```

you should print it out like:

```
print $stringResult;
```

Comment: But its giving me no data. can i use php script to get the data from database within javascript like this?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the code. Actually i am getting the 1st row of data in my array, rest am not getting. Not getting whats the problem in the loop. Please look at my code which i have edited and help me in this. please please

Comment: The for loop is only looping through once and then hitting that break command.  Remove the break command.

Comment: Ya. sorry. But even after removing the break its the same problem. Just to test i had put the break but even then it displays only one data.